# Python argparse - print help for subparsers?

Tags: python, argparse

I've got a series of subparsers, each of which has a help string which summarizes what it does.  When I ask for the overall help argparse will list the subparsers and their help strings.

When I ask for help for a specific subparser it no longer prints out the help string for that subparser.

My question: **Is it possible to get the help string for the subparser when argparse prints out the help for a specific subparser (in addition to the detailed options for that subparser)**

Here's my Minimum Working Example.  Given the following code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command', help='sub-command help')

parser_ag = subparsers.add_parser(  'mySubcommand',
                                    help='Subcommand help')
parser_ag.add_argument( '-g',  action='store_true',
                        help='optional parameter for subcommand')
```

then the line `parser.parse_args(['-h'])` will produce:

```
usage: MWE_SubparserOptionalArgs.py [-h] {mySubcommand} ...

positional arguments:
  {mySubcommand}  sub-command help
    mySubcommand  Subcommand help  <============================== Note the 'Subcommand help' string here!!!

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
```

The line `parser.parse_args('mySubcommand -h'.split())` will produce:

```
usage: MWE_SubparserOptionalArgs.py mySubcommand [-h] [-g]
 <================================  It would be nice for the 'Subcommand help' string to appear here!
optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -g          optional parameter for subcommand
```

My question is: is it possible to get argparse to print out the 'Subcommand help' string along with the help information for the mySubcommand subparser?

Thanks in advance - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [argparse subparser --help output doesn't show the subparser's description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194874/argparse-subparser-help-output-doesnt-show-the-subparsers-description)

Comment: It does!  Thank you for finding that!